# Improving lightbox animation with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, lightbox

I've created a basic lightbox popup in CSS and I'm trying to implement a better open/close animation in JS, but I'm not sure how. I've looked around, but couldn't find much specifically for this, but rather entire JS solutions. I'm using `.fadeToggle`, but it's not very smooth.

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="popup-overlay"></div>
<div class="popup">
  <span class="close-button">
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-top"></div>
    <div class="menu-bar menu-bar-bottom"></div>
  </span>
  <div>
    <h2>Heading</h2>
    <div>
      <p>Content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.popup .close-button, .popup-overlay').on('click', function() {
  $('.popup').fadeToggle('fast');
  $('.popup-overlay').fadeToggle('fast');
});
```

Comment: "_I'm trying to implement a better open/close animation in JS, but I'm not sure how_" - can you be more explicit? In what specific sense do you mean "better"?

Comment: @Rounin Sorry, something quick and smooth like the open/close animation on the "Default" lightbox here: http://noelboss.github.io/featherlight/.

Answer (score 1):

This was a challenge for me, because I've only ever written lightboxes in native javascript before, never in jQuery.

I tried to do something with the jquery animations `.fadeIn()`, `.fadeOut()` and `.delay()`, but in the end, as you see, I went back to CSS `transition: opacity` and javascript `setTimeout()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('button').click(function(){
        $('body').append('<div></div>');
        $('div').addClass('lightbox');

        var lightbox = $('.lightbox');

        lightbox.css({
            'position':'absolute',
            'top':'0',
            'left':'0',
            'width':'100%',
            'height':'100%',
            'background-color':'rgb(0,0,0)',
            'opacity':'0',
            'transition':'opacity 1s ease-out',
        });

        lightbox.hover(function(){
            $(this).css('opacity','0.8');
        });

        lightbox.click(function(){
            $(this).css('opacity','0');
            setTimeout(function(){lightbox.remove();}, 1000);
        });
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Lightbox!</button>
```